# Not able to compile when specifying CSL in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, csl, pandoc-citeproc

I'm writing an article in R markdown using a citation library generated in Mendeley. My document compiles   fine with references when I'm not specifying citation style.

```
bibliography: library.bib
```

When I specify the CSL:

```
bibliography: library.bib
csl: stroke.csl
```

I get the following error:
pandoc-citeproc.exe: PandocResourceNotFound "stroke.csl"
Error running filter C:/PROGRA~1/Pandoc/pandoc-citeproc.exe:
Filter returned error status 1
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 83
Execution halted

I have tried different citationstyles from:
https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles

I appreciate any help.

Comment: I get this error when `pandoc` cannot find the citation style file (.CSL). Is the file `stroke.csl` in the same directory as the .RMD file you are trying to knitt?

Comment: I thought I had put the csl file in the same directory. Turns out, I had mixed up two directories. Thank you for the fix.

Comment: Oh, ok. It is tis simple. Will put this as an answer that you can accept to close this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is caused by `pandoc-citeproc` that cannot find the .CSL file. Check whether the .CSL file `stroke.csl` is in the same directory as the .RMD file you knit.